# Failed to get properties: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1'

Tags: systemd

I am facing  issue when I try to execute the systemctl.

```
$ systemctl status consul.service
Failed to get properties: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
```

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep systemd-shim` and `dpkg -S org.freedesktop.systemd1` please edit your queston for output.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. For some reason `systemd1` seems to crash 1-2 times a week and go into "activatable" state.

Output from `busctl --list | grep systemd1` is:

```
org.freedesktop.systemd1                                    - -               -                (activatable) -                         -
```

Output from `dpkg -l | grep systemd-shim` is empty.

Output put from `dpkg -S org.freedesktop.systemd1`:

```
systemd: /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service
systemd: /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.systemd1.policy
systemd: /usr/share/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.systemd1.conf
systemd: /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service
```

I have been able to restart it with `sudo kill 1` which doesn't feel really good ...